# Reciprocal Integral

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

I saw the proof on Youtube on integral$\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$ and it all made sense.

But my initial proof was wrong and I dont know why. Here is how it goes.

From the formulae $$\int{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}dx = \arctan x$$

Question:
  $$\int{\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}}dx=\frac{1}{a^2}\int\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}dx=\frac{1}{a^2}\arctan \left(\frac xa\right) + c $$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Your second transition is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: if $F'(x)=f(x)$, then what is $\displaystyle\int f(kx)\,\mathrm dx$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule of derivatives,
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(nx+b)=f'(nx+b).n$$
Thus,
$$\int f'(nx+b) dx=\frac1n f(nx+b)$$
Here, $f(x) = \arctan x$, $n=\frac1a$ and $b=0$.
Therefore,
$$\int f'\left(\frac xa\right) dx=\int \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}dx = \frac{1}{\frac 1a}\arctan \left(\frac xa\right) +c=a\arctan \left(\frac xa\right) +c$$
which gives,

$$\frac{1}{a^2}\int f'\left(\frac xa\right) dx=\frac 1a \arctan \left(\frac xa\right) +c$$

Answer (score 0):

Your transition
$$\frac1{a^2}\int\frac1{1+(x/a)^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac1{a^2}\arctan\left(\frac1a\right)+c_1$$
is incorrect. Please notice that in general, given an integrable function $f$ with its primitive $F$, the following identity holds for any $k$ and $c_2$:
$$\int f(kx)\mathrm dx=\frac1k F(kx)+c_2,$$
which is easily proven using the chain rule:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac1k F(kx)+c_2\right)=\frac1k\frac{\mathrm dF(kx)}{\mathrm dx}+0=\frac1k\frac{\mathrm dF(kx)}{\mathrm d(kx)}\frac{\mathrm d(kx)}{\mathrm dx}=\frac1k f(x)\frac{k\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}=f(x).$$
Using the identity just proven, to evaluate
$$I=\frac1{a^2}\int\frac1{1+(x/a)^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
we set $k=1/a\implies1/k=a$ and get
$$I=\frac1a\arctan\left(\frac xa\right)+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

When you face situations like $$I=\int{\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}}$$ the most natural first change of variable is $x=ay$ which makes $dx=a\,dy$. So, replacing $$I=\int{\frac{a\,dy}{a^2+a^2y^2}}=\frac 1a\int{\frac{1}{1+y^2}}dy$$